# Google chrome install in kali linux

Tags: linux, google-chrome, installation

When i am going to enter in google chrome then show " Please start Google chrome as a normal user. If you need to run as root for development, return with the --no-sandbox flag."

Then i command in terminal "/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable %U --no-sandbox --user-data-dir &" this and i entered chrome but then "You are using an unsupported command-line flag: --no-sandbox. Stabilty and security will suffer."  this message show me.
Again and again i'm suffering it when i enter in chrome.
Help me please.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to create a new user and start chrome with this user account:

```
useradd testuser
```

Then you switch to that account:

```
su testuser
```

And start chrome like you tried before:

```
/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me (Fedora 26 - google-chrome)

On my system /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable is a link to /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome  which is the start-up script.

I edited this file commenting out the last line:

exec -a "$0" "$HERE/chrome" "$@"

And replacing it with:

exec -a "$0" "$HERE/chrome" "$@" --user-data-dir --test-type --no-sandbox

I suppose you could quickly test on Kali with:

/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable %U --user-data-dir --test-type --no-sandbox&

Comment: What is `--test-type`? Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.